# How to loop over strings in column which only have 2 decimal points such as 100.00.0?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several csv files which I have to work through and I am running some function lambda on one of the columns which has elements in the form

> 1000.50.0

now I only want to run my function lambda when the element has 2 decimal points. Some of the csv files have no decimal points and some have one.

fundamentally what I want to do is

> if (row of column contains two decimal points): run Lambda

Whats the most efficient way of doing this for a pandas df? is there a way to do this in clean pandas notation?

ideally I would want to do it over the whole Dataframe rather than looping through each individual element and if there are 2 decimal points in one element of a csv, its in the whole column. So maybe scan only the first element of the column?

Answer (score -1):

Write a function that checks for the condition and only runs a secondary function if it is True:

```
check_condition_then_run(input_string):
    if input_string.count('.') == 2:
        return run_complicated_function(input_string=input_string)
    else:
        return input_string


run(input_string=input_string):
    pass


df = pd.DataFrame ... # etc
df['result'] = df['column_with_strings'].apply(check_condition_then_run)
```

Not sure whether you care about the returned value or not, but this way is stored in the `result` column.